# EasyAdmin 3 : Filter for property of a propert

Tags: filter, easyadmin

I have 3 Entities : Country, Region, City
A region has a country property, and the city had a region property.
In the city crud controller, I'd like to add a filter by country.
I try to do

```
return $filters
        ->add('region.country')
```

But I have this error : Call to a member function getAsDto() on array

And I also try to add a getCountry in my City entity, which return region.getCountry value, and then do

```
return $filters
        ->add(EntityFilter::new('country'))
```

But I have this error :
An error has occurred resolving the options of the form "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType": The required option "class" is missing.

Is there a simple way to do a filter on a parent of an object in my entity ?

Comment: You have to create a custom filter: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#custom-filters

And then use it as an unmaped filter: https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#unmapped-filters

Answer (score -2):

Have you [tried](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#unmapped-filters):

```php
        ->add(EntityFilter::new('country')->mapped(false))
```

?

Comment: The `EntityFilter` does not have any mapped method. The `mapped` method is only available for custom filters. Please check : https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/filters.html#unmapped-filters